# Prolog - Cleaner way to define a rule

Tags: prolog

Just started out programming a bit in Prolog but I feel like I've either misunderstood some concept or maybe you have to have more rules.

I would like it so it checks that the son is male and has at least one parent (father/mother)

```
% Son
son(X, Y):- male(X), father(Y, X).
son(X, Y):- male(X), mother(Y, X).
```

Is there any way to combine this easily so I don't need two rows which are similar? Maybe something like: Check if `X` is a male, then check if he has a father, if not check if he has a mother. Only return if `X` is a male and has a father and/or mother.

Comment: Please don't put answers in the question. If there is an answer you can accept do that. If not, then write your own answer. Questions are for questions and answers are for answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want an explicit disjunction, you can instead write:

```
son(X, Y) :- male(X), (father(Y, X); mother(Y, X)).
```

Here I used `;/2` operator. `A ; B` tries the goal `A` first and if that does not succeed tries `B`.

With the following data, we can see the only advantage is that `male(X)` queried twice:

```
male(a).
father(b, a).
mother(c, a).
```

Trace of your original code:

```
      1    1  Call: son(a,c) ? 
      2    2  Call: male(a) ? 
      2    2  Exit: male(a) ? 
      3    2  Call: father(c,a) ? 
      3    2  Fail: father(c,a) ? 
      2    2  Call: male(a) ?              ; <--- just this is not queried
      2    2  Exit: male(a) ? 
      3    2  Call: mother(c,a) ? 
      3    2  Exit: mother(c,a) ? 
      1    1  Exit: son(a,c) ?
```

Trace of the new code using `;/2` disjunction.

```
      1    1  Call: son(a,c) ? 
      2    2  Call: male(a) ? 
      2    2  Exit: male(a) ? 
      3    2  Call: father(c,a) ? 
      3    2  Fail: father(c,a) ? 
      3    2  Call: mother(c,a) ? 
      3    2  Exit: mother(c,a) ? 
      1    1  Exit: son(a,c) ?
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use an auxiliary predicate `parent/2` for subsuming `father/2` and `mother/2`:

```
parent(A, B) :- father(A, B).
parent(A, B) :- mother(A, B).

son(A, B) :- male(A), parent(B, A).
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your wording, not the code you wrote, it is

```
son(S):- male(S), setof( Y, (mother(Y,S) ; father(Y,S)), _).
```

Like you said, a son is some*one* who's male and has *at least one*  parent (or both of them).

The difference from the other answers is that the same person isn't reported twice if he has both a father and a mother:

```
2 ?- [user].
son(S):- male(S), setof( Y, (mother(Y,S) ; father(Y,S)), _).
|: male(a).
|: father(b,a).
|: mother(c,a).
|: 
true.

3 ?- son(X).
X = a.
```

Comment: Are you sure? Take `male(a). father(b,ax). mother(c,ax).` ...

Comment: @false it was a typo. :) thanks for catching it!

Comment: `setof(t, Y^ ( mother(Y,S) ; father(Y,S) ), _)` seems more appropriate.

Comment: @false is there any difference?

Comment: In highly industrialized cases as this one? A good implementation of `setof/3` may take advantage of the fact that no sorting is needed in this case.

Comment: @false aha, thanks for the clarification! here it doesn't matter though, so I'll leave this code as is, as it seems to be simpler.

Comment: And, instead of `findall/3` in might just use `countall/2` which is much cheaper. It cannot replace `!(ground(S)), setof(t, Y^ ( mother(Y,S) ; father(Y,S) ), _)` by `\+ \+ ( mother(_,S) ; father(_, S) )` directly, it would need to know that `mother/2` and `father/2` are pure without error and terminating. So that would require some analysis.

Comment: @false I see. I never have my implementer's hat on when I write Prolog, because I don't have that hat. :) :) my primary concern is clarity (after correctness of course). BTW I was thinking of just replacing that `setof(...)` with `once(...)`. or `!` !! (a *radical* thought...)

Comment: For the sake of clarity, it is much cleaner to say that `Y` just exists, whereas you pretend as if you where interested in `Y`. Only by reading the goal to the end is your real intention revealed.

Answer (score -1):

I would probably do something like this because it better expresses intent:

```
son( X , Y ) :- male(X), parent(Y,X) .

parent( Y, X ) :- mother(Y,X) .
parent( Y, X ) :- father(Y,X) .
```

Comment: That doesn't work correctly linking a son with his parent. It just returns somebody that is male and somebody that is a parent, but does not guarantee they are actually parent and son.